# Code coverage with clang++

Tags: code-coverage, clang++

Is there a way to find code coverage using clang++ for C++ code.

I know gcov but it works only on the code compiled with GCC.

Comment: Which C++ dialect do you want to process, if not GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Clang should be able to generate code coverage these days (taking the same command line arguements as gcc), but you will probably want a newish build and I'm still having trouble running lcov on the output. (see [Clang Code Coverage Invalid Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758126/clang-code-coverage-invalid-output))

Comment: There's some info here that's pertinent to the original question, but it reads like you're trying to ask a question of your own. If so, you should post a new question yourself (after searching to see if it's been answered already, of course).

Comment: I did originally think of making a new question, but this one seemed quite closely related to mind and in the end didn't deem myself worthy of a new question. That said, if a new question is the "done thing" I don't mind moving.

Comment: Don't worry, you're worthy. The fact that you demonstrate at least a basic understanding of the issue, you've tried something, you described it in detail, and you're trying to solve a specific problem would make it better than a large number of the questions asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tool called [kcov](https://github.com/SimonKagstrom/kcov) which can collect code coverage as long as you compile with debug info (-g), regardless of the compiler.

It also has a plugin for the address-sanitizer coverage generator, although that stuff isn't working very well yet.

I'd say it's a lot more straight-forward to use than gcov+lcov.