# Clang Code Coverage Invalid Output

Tags: clang, code-coverage, clang++

So I've checked out and built the clang trunk by following these instructions http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html. I can build my binary with --coverage and run it to get the .gcno and .gcda files, but when I run lcov I get "GENINFO: ... reached unexpected end of file".

Now I'm stuck and came to SO to look for help :)

I'm working with Ubuntu 13.04 and writing c++11, just in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with clang with lcov on Ubuntu 13.04.
Here is the solution which worked for me on more than one Ubuntu setup.

1. You will find there are two versions of gcov on Ubuntu. gcov-4.6.4 & gcov-4.7.3. By default the gcov link is set to gcov-4.7.3. Change that to gcov-4.6.4
2. Furthermore, use lcov version 1.10 instead of what is available via apt-get install

This should generate the code coverage report.

EDIT: Mine was a upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04. Just in case you don't see two versions of gcov.

Comment: Thanks. I had to `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6` to get gcov 4.6.4, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Just summarising the steps for the answer already shared by @Himanshu in case somebody's looking for the exact steps to go about it:

Install gcc 4.6

`sudo apt-get-install -y gcc-4.6`

I couldn’t find locv 1.10 version out of the box so I compiled it myself:

`git clone https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov.git`

`cd lcov`

Switch to a new branch with the commit that published lcov 1.10 version as base

`git checkout -b 1_10 b5c1bdd`

Compile lcov

`sudo make install`

Confirm that lcov installed is 1.10

`lcov --version`

With all these things in place, use the command:

`lcov --gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-4.6 --capture -d gcov_data/ -o gcov_data/coverage.info`

This avoids tinkering with the link of the default `gcov` on the system.

Then generate the visual coverage file

`genhtml -o gcov_data/html gcov_data/coverage.info`

where `gcov_data` is the folder containing the `gcno` and `gcda` files.